# Find capitalised string with regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'm having trouble matching capitalised words with regex (separated by spaces)

```
s = "Show XYZ Dimensions"
regex = re.sub("^[A-Z]$", "", s)
```

I thought would find "XYZ"

```
regex = re.sub("[A-Z]", "", s) # wrong! S XYZ D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `^[A-Z]$` denotes a *whole* string which is made up *entirely* by 1 upper case letter.

If you are after entire words which are exclusively made up from upper case letters, then you need to use something like so: `\b[A-Z]+\b` (example [here](https://regex101.com/r/xP1eF9/1)).

This pattern will look for one or more upper case letters which are preceded by a white space, the beginning or end of the string.